# iis7.5 error: The resource object with key 'XXX' was not found

Tags: asp.net, app-globalresources

I have a website which i have deployed successfully many times.

In a specific server (windows 2008 R2 IIS7.5) I am getting the error:

> The resource object with key 'GoToLastExistingData' was not found.

The code is in a .aspx page:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGetData" CssClass="gotoLastExisting" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Strings ,GoToLastExistingData %>" OnClick="btnGetData_Click"/>
```

The key exists - i have deployed this site many times before.

The resx file are compiled to a `App_GlobalResources.dll` file.

What am i missing?

Comment: Perhaps a different default language on that server?

Comment: But i have a default App_GlobalResources.dll file. shouldn't that cover me?